# Centering page in CSS

Tags: html, css, center

I would need help with centering a page in CSS. The problem is, that I don´t know almost anything from CSS. I tried few things I found here on stack overflow, but nothing seems to work. I personally didn´t write the code, I just need to center the whole page. This is the part of the code, that, in my opinion, is the one I need to adjust. If not, please tell me which part of the code should I adjust to make it work. I would be very thankful for any help and ideas.

```
/* Main Layout */
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}
body {
    font:59%/1.2 Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color:#000;
    background: #eee url(http://www.kovari.cz/images/download.jpg) repeat;
}
```

Comment: Please read the titles of the options in the editor... You just block quoted the code instead of highlighting it

Comment: Not sure why 90% of the answers say you can't center the page using the body tag...

Comment: @Shomz you can but it's bad

Comment: @Mr.Alien Why would it be bad? Unless you need something "behind" the content to be 100% wide, nothing wrong with using body as a wrapper.

Comment: @Shomz agreed, but we have other semantic elements like `div` to be used as a wrapper, which would be much more preferred compared to centering a `body` tag

Comment: @Mr.Alien, I just told him that after he downvoted my answer.. Shameful on you Shomz, NOT cool!

Comment: I know about the div elements. The problem is, that I got no idea how CSS works, so the body changes were more intuitive for me. Thank you all for answers, it works now.

Comment: @user3019115 Think of the body as (almost) the main div element - from the structural standpoint, they are quite similar.

Comment: @Shomz OP always give crappy codes, we make it better right? So we should provide them with best solution of all.. and when it comes to semantics, it's never spam, one can simply use bullet symbols before words and `<br />` after each item to make an unordered list, doesn't mean we shouldn't use `ul` and `li` right? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 757px !important; /* this line is pre-existing css */
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked for me pretty well. Have a nice weekend.

Comment: Can you add some explanation to make your answer better? and **DON'T** use `!important`

Comment: When you use !important, you’re disrupting the natural flow of your rules, giving more weight to rules that are undeserving of such weight. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Comment: the width part of the css was already there-- I left that alone. It was the margin bit that I changed.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to center it, you need to know the width of it. Currently, the body width is not defined, so it defaults to 100% (browser width). To make things work, you'd need something like this (let's assume the width is 960):

```
body {
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GSuwg/)

Answer (score 1):

The above code is only a body properties, you shouldn't center the page like that.
(Well you can but its better to center it with a wrap div)

I am assuming you have assigned a *class* `.container` to a `div` element you need to center...

For example :

`.container` will wrap your content, in CSS you would do this.

```
.container {
   width: ; /* % or px */
   margin: auto 0; /* This will center this DIV in the middle */
}
```

now inside this container you want to add rest of your content / other `div` elements.

I hope you get the general idea how this works, best of luck with your project.

Comment: Nothings bad about this.. infact this should be selected as a correct answer, anyways +1

Answer (score 0):

center the content in the body tag

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
```

You can also use:

```
.content {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

This will center the element with the class content

Comment: You do not need text-align: center

Answer (score 0):

You use margin auto property and a width.

```
.page {
  width: 978px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/aS3h3/1/
http://fiddle.jshell.net/aS3h3/1/show/

Answer (score 0):

I went to the page, http://www.kovari.cz/. If that's what you speak of, redefine this rule like so:

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 757px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Center</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #ccc;
    text-align: center; /* hack para o IE */
}

#everything {
    width: 760px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left; /* IE Hack */
}

#content {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #eee;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="everything">
        <div id="content">
            <h1>Center of the page</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The hack is not needed anymore. This was for IE6.

Comment: Well... some companies still use it, unfortunately legacy systems will always be there.

Comment: IMO, we shouldn't really keep showing IE6 hacks - that's what kept it alive in the first place: the neverending support for a broken product. I was really supporting those 'Your browser seems outdated' popups to encourage companies and everyone to enter the 21st century - it's really not that hard.

Answer (score -1):

here is code example for you

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    text-align:center;
    }

#Content {
    width:600px;
    margin:0px auto; /* Right and left margin widths set to "auto" */
    border:1px dashed #333;
    background-color:#eee;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="Content">
centered content
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Tutorial Link](http://www.wikihow.com/Center-Web-Page-Content-Using-CSS)

Comment: Why don't you pull out some of the instructions from there and add them as a quoted text? Because, giving just a link is not really helpful (not to mention that the link might change one day).